How to run a program after the last modification of a file with systemd?
I'd like to run a program after the last modification of a particular file. The program should not be run concurrently with itself. If the file is modified while the program is running, it should be run again. If the file is modified multiple times, it should not be run multiple times as a result.
This setting can mostly be modeled with systemd units. A .service unit with Type=oneshot and RemainAfterExit=no does not run concurrently with itself. It can be activated with a .path unit configured with PathModified=... and it'll coalesce multiple modifications into one activation. So far so great. If the file is modified while the unit is running, that modification will be turned into an activation and this activation is discarded as the unit already is running. Hence, the program will not be run again.
Is there a variant that meets all relevant properties? Is there a different approach that works better?
